# innerHTML is encoded in Chrome only

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Ok, so I display some svg using external svg files in which I have some style as follows :

```
    <style type="text/css">
<![CDATA[
    .st1 {fill:#ffffff;stroke:#808080;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:0.5;stroke-width:0.75}
    .st2 {fill:#444444;font-family:Calibri;font-size:0.833336em;font-weight:bold}
    .st3 {fill:#f8eccc;stroke:none;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:0.75}
    .st4 {fill:#444444;font-family:Calibri;font-size:0.75em;font-weight:bold}
]]>
</style>
```

I want to add some style using javascript doing like this :

```
    console.log("style innerHTML before :\n" + document.querySelector(elementOrSelector).contentDocument.querySelector("style").innerHTML);
    var styleContent = document.querySelector(elementOrSelector).contentDocument.querySelector("style").innerHTML;
    styleContent = styleContent.slice(0, styleContent.lastIndexOf("}") + 1) + "\n\t\trect:hover {fill:#698B89}\n\t]]>\n";
    document.querySelector(elementOrSelector).contentDocument.querySelector("style").innerHTML = styleContent;
    console.log("style innerHTML after :\n" + document.querySelector(elementOrSelector).contentDocument.querySelector("style").innerHTML);
```

It works fine in Firefox, my console shows for the inner HTML after modification :

```
<![CDATA[
.st1 {fill:#ffffff;stroke:#808080;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:0.5;stroke-width:0.75}
.st2 {fill:#444444;font-family:Calibri;font-size:0.833336em;font-weight:bold}
.st3 {fill:#f8eccc;stroke:none;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:0.75}
.st4 {fill:#444444;font-family:Calibri;font-size:0.75em;font-weight:bold}
rect:hover {fill:#698B89}
]]>
```

But in Chrome it fails badly, the console shows :

```
&lt;![CDATA[
.st1 {fill:#ffffff;stroke:#808080;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:0.5;stroke-width:0.75}
.st2 {fill:#444444;font-family:Calibri;font-size:0.833336em;font-weight:bold}
.st3 {fill:#f8eccc;stroke:none;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:0.75}
.st4 {fill:#444444;font-family:Calibri;font-size:0.75em;font-weight:bold}
rect:hover {fill:#698B89}
]]&gt;
```

so my `<`and `>` are not set properly, I have the `&lt;` and `&gt;` entities instead, and this in Chrome only.

Comment: So either drop the CDATA or externalise the css after dropping the CDATA

Comment: I can't do that, I have many svg generated by a sofware and they all have their own style properties. And the CDATA is necessary for styling in svg if I'm not mistaking.

Comment: @Ellone cant you include an external css file without CDATA ? basically not using inline css..

Comment: So I would need to insert another element in the svg DOM (`<link rel="stylesheet" ...>`) to include a new stylesheet for just some properties ?
There is probably a way to make this work on Chrome, to force it to interpret the entities. Firefox does it natively apparently.

Comment: Is the page xhtml? If not, drop the cdata. I have never used cdata in css - I do not even see any entities that need escaping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is caused by differences across various browsers when handling DOM nodes using method `Element.innerHTML()` .This becomes apparent when inspecting the `<style>` node before any manipulation takes place. This node contains three child nodes in all browsers: `[text, cdata-section, text]`. Where the two nodes of type `text` just contain any whitespace around the `cdata-section`.

Using method `Element.innerHTML()` will retain this DOM structure in FF and IE by replacing it with an updated `<style>` element having the same DOM subtree structure. Chrome, however, will parse the updated `styleContent` string as character data and create just one node of type `text`. Since the `<style>` element only permits character data content Chrome seems to also escape any markup contained within. Hence, your `style` will afterwards consist of only one text node in Chrome, which is of no use for further processing.

I have set up a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/s11FuY0ixJOoyXp2B5Kd?p=preview) demonstrating a more robust solution:

```
// Get style node.
var style = document.querySelector("object").contentDocument.querySelector("style");

// Extract CDATA-Section from style's childNodes.
var cdata = getCDATA(style.childNodes);

// Manipulate CDATA content.
var styleContent = cdata.textContent;
styleContent += "\n\t\tpath:hover {fill:#698B89;}";

// Update CDATA-section node.
cdata.textContent = styleContent;

function getCDATA(nodelist) {
    for (var i=0; i < nodelist.length; i++) {
        var node = nodelist.item(i);
        if (node.nodeType == Element.CDATA_SECTION_NODE) {
            return node;
        }
    }
}
```

Doing it this way, you get a reference to the node of type `cdata-section` enabling you to easily manipulate its `textContent`. Because you are not forcing the browser to rebuild part of its DOM tree by using `Element.innerHTML()` the structure of the `<style>` DOM subtree will remain unchanged across browsers giving consistent results.

Comment: Something weird occured in Chrome. With FF it works still fine. However with Chrome it works only with the first SVG. When I change the displayed SVG, the new style I added is lost.

Comment: Now I am completely lost. The newly added style rules aren't persistent ones, they belong to exactly the one svg they were added to and will live just as long as this svg exists as a dom object. When replacing the svg with another one you will obviously have to re-apply your new styles. It's hard to judge because you didn't provide much information about the setup you are using them in. Please fill in some more details and/or provide an example which explains your environment.

Comment: Well, I didn't manage to reproduce the same behavior yet, but here is a plunker so you can have a better idea : http://embed.plnkr.co/0nufcYZpE3ZzGxKQmUkf/preview (click on left menu to change svg)
I'm adding the styles to svg DOM every time I instanciate a new svgpanzoom (l.1480 of svgpanzoom).
And a new svgpanzoom is created everytime I change my svg via the `changeSVG()` function
(Running locally changes the behavior weirdly...)
Bugs are we need to click twice to do the change properly.